# How to override the '=' command?

Tags: indentation

I cannot convince vim to apply the coding-style I'd like to (`cindent` and friends).

However, integrating `clang-format.py` (which uses the .clang-format of my project) actually makes me totally happy.

Except that I have the reflex of using the <kbd>=</kbd> + *motion*-command. Which is actually very nice to indent a region or the whole file.

How can I instruct vim to override the default functionality? I read about equalprg, but I'm unsure how to set it to make it work with clang-format.

Comment: How about installing Rhysd's `vim-clang-format` plugin, together with its requirements (especially `vim-operator-user`), and then map `=` to `<Plug>(operator-clang-format)`? Plugin link: https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format

Comment: Thank you @VanLaser Do you also know how to make it work with the motion: `==` for one line and `gg=G` for the whole buffer?

Comment: @VanLaser sorry for my reluctance - I was simply not believing: your comment works as expected. Make it an answer please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have nothing against a plugin install, Rhysd's [vim-clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format) may be a valid solution, instead of a custom `equalprg`.

As the documentation states, with Kana's [vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) dependency installed, you can map `=` to `<Plug>(operator-clang-format)` (to function as a full operator) and use it with motions / text-objects such as `==` or `=G`.

You should create a *buffer local mapping*, only for C,C++ and Objective-C filetypes, to let default `=` otherwise untouched:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc map <buffer> = <Plug>(operator-clang-format)
```