# Setting C++ indentation level?

Tags: indentation, neovim

I'm using basically the formatting of the Google C++ Style Guide. How can I configure neovim to use these settings for C++? On the other hand, for pure C, I would like it to use the BSD style.

Currently, I just type code and then run clang-format (through the google codefmt plugin), which takes care of formatting. But it would be nicer to automatically get the correct indentation levels etc. when I hit return after an opening bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure different styles of C/C++ indenting by setting `'cindent'` and `'cinoptions'`.

See `:help cinoptions-values` for more details on what can be configured and `:help C-indenting` for information on C indenting in general.

You can have different settings for C and C++ by placing your configuration in two locations:

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
set cindent
set cinoptions=<the options you want for C>
```

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
set cindent
set cinoptions=<the options you want for C++>
```

You might also like to take a look at [this question about using clang-format for the `=` command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/how-to-override-the-command).

Vim also allows you to set up completely custom indenting using an indent expression. (See `:help 'indentexpr'`) This is what [the script you mention in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14959/setting-c-indentation-level/14960#comment25636_14960) does. You can install that for CPP by renaming the file and placing it in the location:

```
~/.vim/indent/cpp.vim
```

You can find more details at `:help 30.3` and `:help indent-expression`.

Comment: Are these put in the same place in neovim? There's also the following file: https://github.com/vim-scripts/google.vim/blob/master/indent/google.vim do you know how to use it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. So I put the google.vim file into ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/cpp and when starting Neovim in debug mode, I see the following in the logs: `line 17: sourcing "/home/eof/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/cpp/google.vim"
finished sourcing /home/eof/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/cpp/google.vim` However, if I type `int main(void) {` and hit enter in a buffer named test.cc (I see cpp in airline, so it's in the right mode), the cursor jumps to column 8 instead of column 2.

Comment: @eof See my updated answer.